# Ayuda para consultar varias tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito extraer los datos de varias tablas, para lo cual hice un select de la pregunta a la cual se apuntaron las personas y el ID de esa pregunta corresponde al id 22 de la tabla "Respuestas". Ahora bien, una vez filtrado esto necesito saber quiénes fueron las personas con nombre y apellido que apuntaron a esta pregunta y si se puede saber a que curso también. Les agradeceré su ayuda.
`select * from Respuestas where     PreguntaId = '22'`

`select Respuestas.PreguntaId from Respuestas, CursoPlaneadoParticipantes, CursoPlaneadoes, Participantes where Respuestas.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId=CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.id`

Sólo del id 22
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y como se relacionan las tablas??  no sirve con unir la primera con la de participantes por UsuarioId?

Comment: Tampoco se entiende correctamente el resultado que necesitas.

Comment: Ok, la primera tabla a la cual hago el select corresponde a la tabla "respuestas" y lo que preciso saber, es de acuerdo a esa respuesta, cuyo id es 22, es saber cuales son las personas que respondieron a la pregunta que corresponde al id 22.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías explicarte y organizar un poco mejor tu pregunta... Aún así, vamos a ver si me enteré bien y lo solucionamos.
Entiendo que lo único que necesitas es `Nombre` y `Apellido` del participante en el curso que corresponde a la Repuesta 22 y el `Nombre` de ese curso, si?
Parece qué únicamente necesitas hacer un JOIN de todas las tablas por los identificadores correctos y sacar en el SELECT los campos que necesitas:

```
SELECT Participantes.Nombre,Participantes.Apellido,Cursos.Nombre AS Curso
FROM Respuestas
INNER JOIN CursoPlaneadoParticipantes  
    ON CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.id=Respuestas.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId
INNER JOIN Participantes  
    ON Participantes.id=CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.ParticipanteId
INNER JOIN CursoPlaneados  
    ON CursoPlaneados.id=CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.CursoPlaneadoId
INNER JOIN Cursos  
    ON Cursos.id=CursoPlaneados.CursoId
WHERE Respuestas.Preguntaid=22
```